# Github workflow push nuget packages

Tags: nuget, github-actions

I am new to GitHub actions.
I have created a `ci.main` workflow. Below is my code.

After running I can't view the package in the repository section.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
     
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
     
    - name: Build
       run: >
            dotnet pack package \
                   -p:Version=1.0.0 \
                   -c Release \
                   -o ./location \
                   --include-source  
        
    - name: Push
      run: >
           dotnet nuget push \
           ./location/*.nupkg \
           --source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/orginization/index.json" \
           --api-key xxxxxxx --skip-duplicate
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the workflow run? you can see it under github>actions

Comment: Pushing xxxxx.3.0.1.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/orginiaztion'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/orginiaztion/
  OK https://nuget.pkg.github.com/orginiaztion/ 533ms
Your package was pushed.
@CodeWizard

Comment: Looks like you're pushing to the organization scope. Have you checked the packages under this organization? See https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/viewing-packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to accomplish this:

## 1. Automagically

If you publish with the generated token GitHub will automatically attach the repo to the package. Just ensure you have added write permissions on the job:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
    steps:
...
    - name: Push
      run: >
           dotnet nuget push \
           ./location/*.nupkg \
           --source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/orginization/index.json" \
           --api-key ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --skip-duplicate
```

## 2. Manually

This is the easiest method, but will have to be done for every package you publish.

Go to the package page and connect the desired repository repositories: [https://github.com/orgs/{org}/packages/nuget/{package}](https://github.com/orgs/%7Borg%7D/packages/nuget/%7Bpackage%7D)

Note that this appears to be a one-time operation, you cannot undo this without deleting your package and re-pushing.

[Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/connecting-a-repository-to-a-package)

## 3. Via Configuration

From [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#publishing-a-package-using-a-nugetconfig-file), by virtue of having 3a, 3b is generated with dotnet pack, but you can manually add to the nuspec if need be.

### 3a. `.csproj`

Add the `RepositoryUrl`

```xml
<RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/{org}/{repo}</RepositoryUrl>
```

### 3b. `.nuspec`

Add the `repository`

```xml
<repository url="https://github.com/{org}/{repo}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As your package is pushed successfully but it's not visible under your repository packages, you need to verify the organization packages as well. You may follow the [Viewing packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/viewing-packages) docs to do that.

Also, according to [Connecting a repository to a package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/connecting-a-repository-to-a-package):

> When you publish a package that is scoped to a personal account or an organization, the package is not linked to a repository by default.

So, you have to manually link the package to your repository if it's already published by following the steps mentioned in the docs above.

And, according to [Publishing a package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#publishing-a-package):

> If you specify a `RepositoryURL` in your `nuget.config` file, the published package will automatically be connected to the specified repository.

So, to make it automatically connect to your repository, you'll have to update your `nuget.config` file accordingly.

Comment: Namespace has to be the organization, there is no 'repo' scope for NuGet packages.

Comment: @aknosis: Do you mean that the `NAMESPACE` can only be the organization?

Comment: as I read your answer it implied to me that `NAMESPACE` should be the repo, I don't believe that was your intent, but how I read it.

Comment: @aknosis: Thank you for your input! I have updated my answer to make it more clear given the context.

Comment: Reads much more clear now, I see documentation has been updated because some of those links are new to me.